# Z3 Relevancy Propagation with Quantifiers

Tags: z3, smt

I've seen examples that manage to return "don't cares" in their solution. I think this takes advantage of Z3's relevancy propagation. (See [SO question 'How do I get Z3 to return minimal model?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291066/how-do-i-get-z3-to-return-minimal-model/16311025#16311025), [SO question 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289410/z3-eliminate-dont-care-variables/28302963'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289410/z3-eliminate-dont-care-variables/28302963), [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/projects/z3/relevancy.pdf)).

This allows:

```
(set-option :smt.auto-config false)

(declare-const x Bool)
(declare-const y Bool)

(assert (or x y))
(assert x)

(check-sat)
(echo "Expect x is true")
(eval x) ; returns true
(echo "Expect y is don't care")
(eval y) ; returns y - i.e don'tcare
```

which returns:

```
sat
Expect x is true
true
Expect y is don't care
y
```

How can I achieve something similar when quantifiers are involved? For instance in the below example it should not matter if the green car has a broken transmission.

```
(set-option :smt.auto-config false)

(declare-sort Car)

(declare-fun working_engine (Car) Bool)
(declare-fun broken_transmission (Car) Bool)

(define-fun allCarsNeedFixing () Bool
  (forall ((c Car))
    (or
      (not (working_engine c))
      (broken_transmission c))))

(declare-const redCar Car)
(assert (working_engine redCar))

(declare-const greenCar Car)
(assert (not (working_engine greenCar)))

(assert allCarsNeedFixing)
(check-sat)

(echo "red car has working engine, expect true")
(eval (working_engine redCar)) ; returns true
(echo "red car has broken transmission, expect true")
(eval (broken_transmission redCar)) ; returns true

(echo "green car has working engine, expect false")
(eval (working_engine greenCar)) ; returns false
(echo "green car has broken transmission, expect don't care")
(eval (broken_transmission greenCar)) ; could return true or false
```

Which returns:

```
sat
red car has working engine, expect true
true
red car has broken transmission, expect true
true
green car has working engine, expect false
false
green car has broken transmission, expect don't care
true
```

How can I get the final result to return a "don't care" as opposed to true?

These examples should execute via [Rise4Fun](https://rise4fun.com/Z3)

Comment: Would help if you also specify what happens and what you expect (or want) to happen.

Comment: @alias I've edited the question to try and make it clearer

Comment: SMT solvers usually don't give this sort of information, and I wouldn't count on z3 supporting this sort of stuff in perpetuity either. A good way would be to explicitly try both options. That is, prove that the value of `y` is irrelevant by establishing `premises /\ y -> conclusions` and also `premises /\ not y -> conclusions`. If you can prove both, then you know `y` is irrelevant to the original problem statement. This is more work obviously, but it should be portable across SMT solvers. (Though in conjunction with quantifiers, your mileage might vary.)